# Oracle query to get all entries having all CAPS in a column

Tags: oracle

I am trying to find a querty which fetches me only rows having all caps data entry . I have used the below code

`Select * from Table
where  REGEXP_LIKE(column, [A-Z])
order by Column`

The above code doesn't work though.

**Data:**
ABD
asb
Adsd
adaddf
ADd
An
DEF

**Required Results**
ABD
DEF

Comment: What about values with non-letter characters such as `A1`: should they be selected or not?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff in this particular instance I was not looking for that . But that probably would have made it a little more difficult

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
select * from table
where column = upper(column)
/
```

Obviously values which are already all CAPS will equal themselves when cast to upper case, and mixed case values won't.

Comment: that was easy . Somehow I kept thing of complex solutions like REGEXP_LIKE :) .Thanks for your help.